# Strength of aluminium plate

Tags: structural-engineering

I need to make a new outboard engine mounting plate, as I have just purchased and larger HP engine. My current plate is made of 12mm thick aluminium plate. I am having problems buying a cut to size piece of 500mmx500mm. Everyone one wants to sell me a full sheet. I might be able to get thinner sheet easier from a scrap yard, my question is, could I use two sheets of thinner aluminium and it being just as strong as a single 12mm plate?

Regards
Doops

Comment: Go to an engineering shop - they cut and use metal so they may cut your piece to the finished size.

Comment: The alloy and heat treat make a difference in strength. You want  T-6 heat treat for any alloy.

Answer (score 1):

#### How many stacked 6mm plates are needed to get the same strength of a 12mm plate

I am assuming that with

> two sheets of thinner aluminium

you mean two 6mm thick sheets that stack up to 12mm of thickness. If this is not the case, look below where I estimate the minimum thickness for just two sheets stacked on top of each other.

If this is the case, and since it's a mounting plate (I assume bending stresses are present) you won't get the same strength out of them as you would out of a 12mm thick sheet, because even if you stack them, they have a gap inbetween where the continuity of the material is interrupted and this makes it very hard for the sheets to exchange shear forces between each other, because the two plates slide rather than "pulling" each other. 
Friction between the two plates isn't strong enough (nor is it reliable) to do this job, so it's usually left out of calculations.

This weakens the structure by a lot. The strength of such a structure is calculated through the section modulus defined as such:

$S=\frac{I_b}{h/2}$

where

$S$: *section modulus* 
$h/2$: *half of the thickness of each sheet used* 
$I_b$: *bending moment of inertia*

In particular, for $n$ beams of rectangle cross section of base $b$ and height $h$ that are stacked on top of each other, the section modulus is calculated as such:

$S=n\cdot\frac{bh^2}{6}$

Now we can calculate the section modulus for both cases (one 12mm plate, two 6mm plates) and see what comes out:

$S_{12mm}=1\cdot\frac{1\cdot12^2}{6}=24 mm^3$

$S_{6mm}=2\cdot\frac{1\cdot6^2}{6}=12 mm^3$

I assumed a base $b=1mm$ but it doesn't change the results as we are interested in the ratio $\frac{S_{6mm}}{S_{12mm}}$ and you can see that **the two 6mm plates stacked are half as strong as the single 12mm plate**, so you would actually need four of those 6mm plates to get the same bending strength of a single 12mm plate and you would get a total thickness of 24mm.

#### What if you wanted the same strength with two stacked plates of the same thickness? How thick would they need to be?

They would of course be thicker than 6mm because, as shown above, you would need 4 of those.

For two plates to have the same strength in bending as a 12mm plate, we need to find their thickness h from:

$\frac{1\cdot12^2}{6}=2\cdot\frac{1\cdot(12a)^2}{6}$

Where $a$ is just a constant that we'll need to find to get the minimun thickness $12\cdot a$ of the two sheets.

$\frac{1\cdot12^2}{6}=2\cdot\frac{1\cdot12^2\cdot a^2}{6}$

and this gives us

$a=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\approxeq 0.707 \rightarrow h_{min}=0.707 \cdot 12\approxeq 8.49mm$

So **you would need two plates whose thickness is at least 8.49mm**.

I used the beam model for these calculations, but the plate model is very similar and only differs by a constant so the ratios found still hold.

#### Conclusions

To add to this, so far we only looked at strength, but there are other issues that come up with using two plates rather than one, such as rigidity and vibrations/noise. Stiffness decreases even faster than strength when you use more plates rather than a single one to achieve the same thickness. This means that the structure will bend more and this could give you problems.

Vibrations also get worse as the stiffness decreases and this could produce more noise, especially when an engine is mounted above. The plates could also bump into each other when vibrating, worsening the issue.

#### EDIT

I forgot to mention that there exist ways to allow two stacked elements to transmit shear forces between one another, but these are a bit too much for this purpose. I think you would spend more and have a harder time generally by choosing this approach.

The idea behind these methods is to add rivets/bolts/welds in a periodic pattern so as to mimick the continuity of the material, but the size and the distance between these joints have to be calculated, or you risk falling into the extremes of underdesigning or overdesigning them, and neither is good.

Bolts and rivets would also create a less regular surface and you would have more troubles when mounting the engine.

Welded joints I think would not be very practical either in your case, as the surface isn't small.

Another thing I forgot to mention is that of course you can change the aluminum alloy for one with greater yield strength to get a higher strength, but again even in this case stiffness will not change much and you will still have that problem.